# Multi module maven project cannot access PagingAndSortingRepository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, repository

I have a multi module maven project and currently I have three modules : repository(where I have all my @Entity classes and my repositories), web (where I have controllers and everything that is related to the UI) and service where I have a task to implement the UserService. I need my service module to be the connection between web and repository. In web, everything is ok, but in my service module pom I have the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>repository</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And in my UserService class I have the following code:

```
@Service
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.project.task.repository")
public class TaskUserService {

@Autowired
private TaskUserRepository taskUserRepository;

public List<TaskUser> getAllUsers() {
    List<TaskUser> users = taskUserRepository.findAll();
    return users;
}
```

However, I get the following error:
Cannot access org.springframework.data.repository.pagingandsortingrepository

I found many solutions on the internet, but none of them seem to work for me and I am pretty sure I have all my dependencies well written.

Any ideas how can I fix this?